# HTML form field with search function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is it possible to have an html text input field show a drop down selection as you type text that matches the possible results?

For example - I have a list of 50 companies. As the person types in the name of one of the companies, it shows the possible matches. Somewhat like Google does, but limited to what the choices given would be.

Comment: As far as I know, this sort of thing is best done with JavaScript and not plain HTML. Maybe consider adding a js tag to your question.

Comment: jQuery auto complete will make this a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

It is only possible with the use of Javascript (as HTML is not Dynamic). Javascript (made easier with the [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) library) is there to edit data (for example HTML) trough the browser side of the web, which means you can edit your website live on view. There are different plug-ins that do this (like: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp), or you could build something yourself.

Answer (score 0):

**Autocomplete** feature it is. This can be easily done using Jquery. There is a nice documentation [here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) .

Example below. Replace the programming language names(with in availableTags) below with your 50 company names. If you feel that giving 50 names here is toomuch you can read them from file as well

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [ //give your company names below
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very cool. And I might find use for it, but I still need to maintain a selection as well since someone might not know the company name.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in just HTML, checkout [selectize.js](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/). Most likely this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a text input that provides suggestions, I would go with the HTML5 standard `<datalist>`.

But since you want to limit the choices the user has, you'll want an enhanced version of the `<select>` element. **[Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)** is what you're looking for. It enhances your standard `<select>` input with a search and other useful stuff while still being accessible, well maintained and good looking out of the box.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work and documentation is very limited on what is needed. The examples were cool though and exactly what I was looking for.